# When should I not use CSRF protection for a form?

Tags: appsec, web-application, csrf

By default, I have CSRF protection for all my forms using a token.

However I noticed another web application that has a similar function to one of my forms. ANd they did not use CSRF token.

So I assumed they did not protect against CSRF attack for that form.

So

question 1) other than CSRF token, there should not be another way to protect against CSRF right?

I am assuming the answer is this is the only way. hence my main question is

question 2) when should you not use CSRF protection?

I know one possible instance which is when the POST form is targeted at external URLs.

I read it at [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Are there other instances when you should not use CSRF protection or unnecessary?

**UPDATE**

a) other methods of CSRF protection include user re-authentication

b) you CAN get away without protecting against CSRF for form POSTBACKs when you do not require the user to be logged in. (see nbnh's answers and comments)

Comment: I think it would help motivate this if you can flesh out your specific application and proposed sequence of forms in the question, as you've hinted at in some other comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, tokens are not the only way to reliably protect against CSRF.
In fact, it was only recently that the packaged libraries were mature enough to warrant reccommendation, before that rolling your own had a high chance of making things worse.

Another way to protect against CSRF is re-authentication.  I.e. asking the user for his password again.
The advantage of this approach is that the technique is familiar to the developers, and unlikely to be messed up. The disadvantage is that it is not transparent to the user.
Nowadays, with most frameworks having the protection built in, and additional libraries available, I would say that CSRF tokens are preferred... but it's not the only way.

As to Q#2, as @nhnb wrote correctly, if no modifications take place, it *might* be okay to leave out the protection.
Though considering how trivial it is in current frameworks, the user transparency, and the minimal overhead, you're probably better off just leaving it in, and not fighting the code to take it out...

Comment: @AviD, reauthentication is not a solution that is accepted by users for CSRF protection. It may be accepted for _really_ dangerous actions (such as transferring money), but it is not a standard solution. /// I agree that the token should not be left out just because it is not required. But it may be desirable to allow linking to form results pages. A common case is to share links to search results.

Comment: @nhnb reauthentication *is* the correct solution, and the most direct. Until not so long ago, it was the *only* recommended solution, since rolling your own token management would *always* be gotten wrong, and very often create more damage than it solves. There are many examples of this used well, even outside of banks, e.g. LinkedIn. The key to that approach is being selective in where you apply it, though.

Comment: @AviD what about an action that any anonymous visitors can perform? for eg, add item to cart without logging in. can i forego CSRF protection in this case?

Comment: The form in question is in a template that i intend to let my users have free rein to customize the look and feel. My users are targeted at those who will be comfortable using Twig and Liquid to customize UI. Having CSRF protection means it will be less intuitive for the web designers. hence motivation behind the questions

Comment: @keisimone as @nhnb said, if there is any "identity" that could be misused, and any "action" being performed, you should have CSRF protection. In your case you could solve this differently, be re-initializing and emptying the cart on login.

Comment: Wrt development process, I'm not familiar with Twig or Liquid, but there are frameworks that let you seperate UI and code (i.e. "codebehind"). Also in many frameworks the CSRF protection is configuration-based, on shouldnt interfere with UI designers.

Comment: ... curious what other people disagree with here...

Comment: @AviD I am using a framework called cakephp where to use CSRF protection the UI requires the use of a FormHelper which is native to the framework. hence requiring my users/designers to be at least somewhat familiar with the framework as well.

Comment: @AviD Judging on the options available to me, I probably would go ahead and just enforce the users to at least know FormHelper code for this protection. SEcurity is important, so i guess I cannot let them get away with normal HTML form

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using tokens is the only way to protect reliably against CSRF attacks.

Whether a protection is required or not depends on the actions the program does with the submitted data.

As a rule of thumb: If data is modified with the permissions or context of the current user, you need the protection.

If no modifications take place, it may be okay to not protect. A common example are search forms and results. Please note that logging which searches are done by which user is a kind of modification and therefore the form needs to be protected.

Comment: what about an action that any anonymous visitors can perform? for eg, add item to cart without logging in. can i forego CSRF protection in this case?

Comment: For actions that anyone can perform without a user context (and without logging), it may be okay to not protect the form. But if it is in the context of a concrete user (even if it is an anonymous one), you need the protection. To expand your example in a likely way: After some time the user will enter his address and billing information and order the content of the shopping cart. For obvious reasons there shall be no items in the cart, he did not place in there himself.